# Error using fread Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a valid file identifier

Tags: matlab, path, fread

I have a code of a function given by my professor. In his Matlab these function works, but in mine generate these error:

> ''Error using fread Invalid file identifier. Use fopen to generate a
> valid file identifier.
>
> Error in funcrion (line 18) A = fread(fileID ,inf, 'uint8');'''

I think that the problem is the Matlab path, however, I set it before, and I'm sure that is correct. For safety, I add both folders with functions than folders with data.

Thank you

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: Higher in your code there should be a line looking like: `fileID=fopen('somefilenameandpath','...');`. This is where your error actually originates. Well done for clearly showing the error message, but you also need to show the code that produced it for anyone here to be able to help further.

Comment: Yep! `fopen` is one of those old-school functions that, if it fails, doesn't raise an error, but returns a status code that you need to check yourself. When you find that fopen call, do like this: `[fileID, errmsg] = fopen(...); if fileID < 0; error('Failed opening file: %s', errmsg); end` and you'll get some more useful debugging info.